# Installing TIGER geocoder?

Tags: postgis, geocoding, windows-7

I am trying to install the tiger geocoder for postGIS. I am using the 2.1 version of postGIS on Windows 7. I am using [this set of instruction](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/postgis_installation.html#install_tiger_geocoder_extension) to do so.

I am confused by what they mean be `edit the paths in the declare_sect column to those that fit your pg, unzip,shp2pgsql, psql, etc path locations.`

Here's the code that I am using to do this.

`INSERT INTO tiger.loader_platform(os, declare_sect, pgbin, wget, unzip_command, psql, path_sep, 
           loader, environ_set_command, county_process_command)
SELECT 'ravimehta', declare_sect, pgbin, wget, unzip_command, psql, path_sep, 
       loader, environ_set_command, county_process_command
  FROM tiger.loader_platform
  WHERE os = 'windows';`

@RyanDalton - I tried to do what you suggested. However, I got the following error.

> ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "unziptool." I'm not sure
>   what I am doing wrong.

Fixed problem by using:

```
UPDATE tiger.loader_platform SET unzip_command = 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' WHERE os = 'ravim';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "paths" they are referring to are the program executables (*.exe) for your system, as mentioned in step 4.  For example, if you are using 7-zip for unzipping data, you would replace:

`<unzip_command>` with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"` in the `SELECT` portion of the SQL statement.

You could make this easier by creating SQL variables representing each item by using the `SET` command, similar to what is shown on page 2 of [PostGIS 2.0 Tiger Geocoder Cheatsheet](http://www.postgis.us/downloads/postgis20_tiger_cheatsheet.pdf) under the heading of "Loader_Generate_Script":

```
SET unzip_command="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this too (almost mindlessly following the PostGIS 2.2.0 Manual) and finally realized that `declare_sect` was just a field in this table multi-line statement of command statements that gets pasted into your script. This is what I had to do to get my username/password accurately set as well as the postgresql version and paths:

```
update tiger.loader_platform set declare_sect=
'TMPDIR="/data/gisdata/temp/"    
UNZIPTOOL=unzip                   
WGETTOOL="/usr/bin/wget"          
export PGBIN=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin   
export PGPORT=5438                
export PGHOST=localhost
export PGUSER=special_user            
export PGPASSWORD=special_password
export PGDATABASE=special_database
PSQL=${PGBIN}/psql                
SHP2PGSQL=${PGBIN}/shp2pgsql      
cd /data/gisdata    
' where os='sh';
```

Now chances are really good that I got here via the wrong path -- I was surprised that the line for export PGBIN was refering to a completely different version of PG -- 9.0. In any case, this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that the instructions in this step are unclear. My interpretation is that you run this command, then edit the value of the declare_sect column in the loader_platform table that's created by the command. The value of the declare_sect column rows should be the path to the os commands listed (e.g. pg, unzip, etc...).