# PostGIS TIGER reverse_geocode() returns state only

Tags: postgis, installation, tiger

I have a clean install of PostGIS 2.1 in Postgres 9.3 on Ubuntu, using apt-get and postgres extensions.

Ran the data loading scripts from [Waiting for PostGIS 2.1 - Install PostGIS Tiger Geocoder as an Extension](http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/206-Waiting-for-PostGIS-2.1-Install-PostGIS-Tiger-Geocoder-as-an-Extension.html).

`normalize_address` works well, but `geocode` returns no result.

Interestingly, `reverse_geocode` is able to find the state, but no finer detailed information.

> SELECT pprint_addy(r.addy[1](http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/206-Waiting-for-PostGIS-2.1-Install-PostGIS-Tiger-Geocoder-as-an-Extension.html)) As st1, pprint_addy(r.addy[2]) As st2, 
>   pprint_addy(r.addy[3]) As st3, array_to_string(r.street, ',') As
>   cross_str FROM reverse_geocode(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.06941
>   42.34225)',4269)) As r;

returns:

> st1   st2 st3 cross_str
>
> MA

Is this a data loading issue or a software install issue?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided (and other guides) don't go into any detail about setting up your environment paths in the tiger.loader_platform table.  Check out [Installing TIGER geocoder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116803) which has more detail.