# Select the correct paths for The TIGER geocoder (linux)

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger, file-path

I'm following [this](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder) tutorial to setup the geocoder.

I'm stuck on the step 2.8.1.4

"edit the paths in the declare_sect column to those that fit Debbie's pg, unzip,shp2pgsql, psql, etc path locations."

The script is not finding any of the files.
E.G. for the PostgreSQL bin I have set:

```
export PGBIN=”/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin”
```

Which is similar to the one in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/149695) answer:

And it seems to have the required files:

[image]

Nevertheless, I'm getting errors when I run `nation_script_load.sh`

```
nation_script_load.sh: 17: nation_script_load.sh: ”/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin”/psql: not found

nation_script_load.sh: 18: nation_script_load.sh: ”/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin”/psql: not found
```

Even the site to get the data seems to be falling:

```
ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE: No such file or directoryftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE/.listing: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The log has ” (unicode U+201D), try using ordinary quotation marks (") in your `export` statement, or just don't use them at all: export `PGBIN=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin`

Comment: Yes, It was that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things,

1. first Richard Law is right in the comments.. Quotes in EXPORT statements should be `"`.
2. If you could run `TABLE tiger.loader_platform` and paste the output, I'd like to see what those variables are set to. Also paste the top of the script generated where the env variables are.
3. Your tiger data is 2015. It's up to you what year you want to use. I would [upgrade `postgis_tiger_geocoder`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/162006/2639).